# volume of $x=(y-3)^2, x = 4$ about x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I used the cylindrical shell method:

radius: $y$

width: $4 - (y-3)^2$

upper limit: $5$

lower limit: $1$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: Your question would be more easily read if you could write it in MathJax. Here's where I learned the basics - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It was an exam question. I memorized it and my solution, because I thought it was a little tough. I'm glad I got it right though!